# Store output array in different array and sort the array values

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I want to know how I can store the output in an array and then sort its values.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int i;
    float[] npoints = new float[10];
    float[] points = new float[10];
    points[0]=(float) 0.3;
    points[1]=(float) 0.2;
    points[2]=(float) 0.4;
    points[3]=(float) 0.5;
    points[4]=(float) 0.6;
    points[5]=(float) 0.0123;

    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        if(points[i]!=0.0)
        {
            npoints[i]=points[i];
            System.out.println(i+":"+points[i]);
        }

    }
    System.out.println(npoints[i]);
}
```

}

Output:

0:0.3
1:0.2
2:0.4
3:0.5
4:0.6
5:0.0123
0.0
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Arrays#sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28float%5B%5D%29):

```
Arrays.sort(points);
```

Note that this method sorts the array *in place*, meaning it will modify the array that you pass as an argument.

If you want to copy the array, you can use `Arrays#copyOf`, and then sort the copy:

```
float[] points = new float[10];
points[0]=(float) 0.3;
points[1]=(float) 0.2;
points[2]=(float) 0.4;
points[3]=(float) 0.5;
points[4]=(float) 0.6;
points[5]=(float) 0.0123;

float[] npoints = Arrays.copyOf(points, points.length);
Arrays.sort(npoints);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(npoints));
// [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0123, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6]
```

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/hpsXM)**.

Comment: how can i store the out put in a different array after for iteration .

Comment: @user1277399: I've added a demo exemplifying it. You can also use `copyOf` instead of the for loop to copy the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Float> arr = new ArrayList<Float>();

for(i=0;i<6;i++)
   {
       if(points[i]!=0.0)
       {
           npoints[i]=points[i];
           System.out.println(i+":"+points[i]);

           arr.add(npoints[i]);
       }

    }
```

Now use `java.util.Comparator` or `java.lang.Comparable` Interface to **Sort them**.....
or if you want to stick with Array...then do `Arrays.sort()`

Answer (score 0):

Use `Arrays.sort(array); or Collections.sort(list);`

Even you can pass custom `Comparator<? super T>` in both for custom ordering element.